# Unable to connect to backend through worklight http adapter in android device

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

i created HTTP adapter for connecting to yahoo weather service and deployed it on worklight server. it works well in worklight simulator and in android emulator but when using it on real android device i am getting following error:

{"invocationContext":null,"errorCode":REQUEST_TIMEOUT","errorMsg":"Request timed out for "http://'192.168.242.1':9080/krishak/apps/services/api/ok/android/query".Make sure the host address is available to the application(especially relevant for Android and iPhone apps)."}

Comment: Is your device connected to the same network as the Worklight Server?

Comment: http://'192.168.242.1':9080 are you *sure* you want those single quotes around the IP address?  That looks really suspicious, though it is possibly irrelevant or just an artifact of the logging code.

Comment: sir, what type of changes are required in app's worklight settings in device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure your device can communicate with the Worklight Server where you have deployed your application and adapter. An easy way to test this is to go into the phones mobile browser and attempt to connect to the Worklight console at a location in the form of the following:

`http://"server address":"port"/"context root"/console`

in your case it looks to be located at:

`http://192.168.242.1:9080/krishak/console`

If your application cannot connect to the console successfully it is likely your device is not on the correct wifi network in order to establish communication. Please attempt this conenction and provide an update so we can provide further investigation.

Comment: Can you provide some more detail please. What happens when you attempt to access the console from the device's browser? Is it able to connect successfully? Also as I see in a comment above the IP address in the location above should not have single quotes around your address. I will need some further information of what you are experiencing in order to do some better problem determination. One thing that may be of use is clicking the details button when the error message occurs on the device side and pasting the contents here.

Comment: How it is working.  Can you please explain the solution in detail @user3365707

Comment: Means to work with real devices it is necessary to host project on a public domain?? @Jaalger2

Comment: @sravanalakshmi.sunkara can you please open a new question explaining the current issues you are having. If you have any specific questions I would be glad to take a look

Comment: can you please tell us what you have made changes, Since you got success in this thing.? As I have same question of you, except single quotes around the IP address part.!